# loading large data in datagridview uisng vb.net in less time

Tags: excel, datagridview, oledb, vb.net-2010, vba

I have an excel sheet with over a million records. When it is loaded on form, it takes around 10 minutes. I want to reduce time. I am using Vb.net and excel.

Answer (score 0):

I have three solution :

1.**pagination**, you can use take and skip method in linq for create pagination

2.**lazy loading**, when user scroll down, load other records.

3.**filter**, before you want to load records ask from user to filter more rows and then load filtered records